# I can't understand what's going wrong in this program

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    int f = 10000;

    int div1 = (powl(10,i));

    int temp1 =  f/div1;

    for(i = 2; temp1 > 1; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n",temp1);
    }
}
```

As far as I know, the value of div1 should be 100,1000,10000... With corresponding increments in I. Then temp1 should be 100,10, then loop stops (?). But I get an endless loop of 10000 10000 10000 10000......

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: its bad formatted + missing a `{`

Comment: `for(i=2;temp1>1;i++)` your loop condition has nothing to do with `i` and `temp1` doesnt change in the loop

Comment: isn't temp1 = f/(powl(10/i)); so a function of i and should change with i?

Comment: that is _before_ the loop not inside.. temp1 doesnt change after initial value

Comment: so if i move the whole expression inside the loop, it should work?

Comment: you really need to go through how a for loop works.. My advice is go through some beginner tutorial in C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` statement should have like this. You missed to call those to statement inside your `for` loop

```
    for(i = 2; temp1 > 1; i++)
    {
        div1 = (powl(10,i));

        temp1 =  f/div1;
        printf("%i\n",temp1);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop checks for `temp1`, but `temp1` is not modified in the loop's body. Try putting the desired modification inside the loop's body or as the last expression in the `for` loop; the variable `i` is perhaps not necessary at all.

Comment: Perhaps there is some misconception here; `temp1 = f/(powl(10/i))` is an expression that is evaluated exactly once, performing a single call to `powl`. It is not a means to magically link `temp1` and `i` in the sense that it changes `temp1` every time that `i` changes, what you perhaps assume based on your wording used in the comment.